# UnknownHostException for server through java client code

Tags: networking, security, firewall, java

I am not able to connect to an remote known server through Java code; java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host exception occurs when connection is tried.

But strangely, I am able to connect to same server through ssh.

*Details:*
Simple Java client when tries to establish connection with Java standalone server, while conneting the exception occurs at following statement:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(ServerIP ServerPort);
```

The port needed is open on server so that externally request can come in.

Again the following is returns false

```
InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP).isReachable(1000)
```

The Server is running on Fedora, Java 5.

FYI: [Java cannot resolve DNS address from AIX: UnknownHostException](https://serverfault.com/questions/22290/java-cannot-resolve-dns-address-from-aix-unknownhostexception) is almost same to my question, but somehow this is neither AIX nor dns related; moreover I feel the issue to be more of Network or firewall issue.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

This is the error you'd expect from a host being firewalled. Can you telnet to the same port on that IP?

Comment: you guessed it right, I cannot telnet, although the netstat show me that the port is open for listening.

netstat -pan | grep 5014 tcp 0 0 :::5014 :::* LISTEN 6212/java

Comment: netstat will only tell you whether the port is listening, not if it's firewalled. It's entirely possible there's something in between blocking traffic, or a iptables/pf/ipfilter on the host, none of which would show up in netstat.

Comment: Recently I checked, I am able to telnet certain ports (the port on which mysql-cluster is running) ; but not any other such as 5000 mentioned earlier. I even tried to use some other ports but to no use.

Comment: Sounds like a firewall issue. E_CONTACT_NETWORK_ADMIN

Answer (score 0):

1. The `Socket` constructor should only attempt to resolve if the `hostName` is `null`, and then it tries to resolve the local host. Is your `/etc/hosts` file set up properly?
2. What does the following code return? (Please use the host name, not the ip ).

   ```
   System.out.println(InetAddress.getByName(hostName));
   ```